# Interactive 2d array that updates based on user selection

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, software-design

Essentially we have a program my team and I are building for a "skiing trip", and without directly copying the teachers notes we are trying to think of how we can do the following.

We have a strict size limit of 12 rows and 4 seats per row. Something essentially like this

```
[1][1][0][1]
[0][1][1][1]
[1][0][0][0]
```

Then, once a person makes a seat selection it will update the array.

```
[1][1][0][1]
[0][1][1][1]
[1][0][1][0]
```

So with this being said, How can I make referencing/updating the seating chart easier on both my teammates and the rest of the code.

Would the best option be to use 12 arrays with 4 options in each and kind of brute force change them?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using nested lists.

```
X = 4
Y = 12

l = [[0 for j in range(X)] for i in range(Y)]

def update_position(x, y):
    l[y][x] = 1 - l[y][x]
    
update_position(3,2)
```

That way you can update a position by simply invoking `update_position`. Take into consideration list indexes start from 0. So for x you could go from 0 to 3 and for y from 0 to 11.

Also, my code will toggle between 1 and 0 so please modify the `update_position` function according to your needs.